# How do I make a button / link to show Source Codes inside <iframe> instead of a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

How do I make that when I click on a button / link instead of a page, that the button / link shows the source codes of a page in the iframe it targets? On an iframe who normally has a page on...

That is if to do that is even possible. But if it is then that would be great, because my page has a container iframe showing a web page and if by clicking a button / link that iframe could show the source codes of the page too, that would be perfect.

**I tried:**

```
<a class="button" href="view-source:Func/Math_Calculator_Func.html" target="IFrWin">Show the Source Code for the math function</a>

<iframe src="Func/Math_Calculator_Func.html" name="IFrWin" id="IFrWin" width="100%" height="748px" scrolling="auto" style="overflow:auto; overflow-y:hidden; overflow-x:auto;" valign="middle" align="center" border="0" frameborder="no" noresize></iframe>
```

**I also tried:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function viewsource()
    {
        var oldHTML = document.getElementById('para').innerHTML;
        var newHTML = "" + oldHTML + "";
        var newHTML = newHTML.replace(/</g,"&lt;");
        var newHTML = newHTML.replace(/>/g,"&gt;");
        var newHTML = newHTML.replace(/\t/g,"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
        document.getElementById('IFrWin').innerHTML = newHTML;
        var myIFrame = document.getElementById('IFrWin');
        myIFrame.src=javascript:'"+newHTML+"'";
    }
</script>
<input type="button" onclick="viewsource();" value=" View Source TEST "/>
<iframe src="Func/Math_Calculator_Func.html" name="IFrWin" id="IFrWin" width="100%" height="748px" scrolling="auto" style="overflow:auto; overflow-y:hidden; overflow-x:auto;" valign="middle" align="center" border="0" frameborder="no" noresize></iframe>
```

Both of them did not work.

Comment: Please post your code and show us what you've tried so far

Comment: Okay I added the codes. Did not add it before cause I thought it was easy to understand the question since those codes are dysfunctional anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you are the owner of the source files, you can easily create a copy of the files, change their type to `*.txt` and simply change the source of your iframe to the given document.

This might work out with something along the way of this, you would just have to add the toggle mechanism.

```
document.getElementById('iframe').src = 'path/to/file.txt';
```

Comment: correct..but not shows the html file all contents ...shows only body content..what i do?

Comment: Copy the file and change the `.html` to `*.txt`, this will keep all the content of the file, but the browser will render it as a textfile, not as an HTML-file.

Comment: Yes I am the owner of the files. And yes but that would mean that every time I do an update I will need to delete the old TXT file and replace tit with a new. Is there a way to copy all source code from the HTML automatically to the TXT? So I will not need to make doubles all the time? If not then okay I will make doubles all the time when I update it.

Comment: You can write a bash-script that copies and renames the files, which would help you somewhat with automation of the process.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
                <head>
                <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" /> </script>
                <script type="text/javascript">

                    function viewsource(){
                        $.get('Func/Math_Calculator_Func.html', function(data) { 
                            var oldHTML = data;
                            var newHTML = "" + oldHTML + "";
                            var newHTML = newHTML.replace(/</g,"&lt;");
                            var newHTML = newHTML.replace(/>/g,"&gt;");
                            var newHTML = newHTML.replace(/\t/g,"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
                            document.getElementById('iframe1').innerHTML = newHTML;
                            var myIFrame = document.getElementById('iframe1');
                            myIFrame.src="javascript:'"+newHTML+"'";
                            return1(); //call this function to show alert
                        });
                    }

                </script>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <iframe src="" width="555" height="200" id="iframe1"></iframe>
                    <input type='button' onclick='viewsource()' value='View Source'/>
                </body>
                </html>
```

worked me..!! first check own then to integrate..set file path correctly..
any other doubt plz comment me...

Comment: I tried it, and nothing happens. Tried two ways. One that I used `<iframe src="Func/Math_Calculator_Func.html"` in the and the other with a link and one with a button and still it did not work. So how do I make it to work?

Comment: but this code worked me..i'm not set frame src="" plz check the file path directory or change another file in this area $.get('sample.html', function(data)...then no idea..

Comment: The file directory is perfect, because I have a working iframe with it too. Now when clicking on the button the working frame should show the source code instead of the page. I did add `$.get('Func/Math_Calculator_Func.html', function(data))` nut it still does not work. You may be using the same code, but have you by mistake not forgotten something? Because dis does not work for me. I am using Chrome. Maybe it also depends what browser. If so then the code is not good cause a good code should work on most commercial big browsers such as Chrome.

Comment: i'm also use to chrome browser..but i don't know why such code does not work in your side..sorry...

Comment: Maybe id could be the antivirus, anti malware or the add blocker. In that case I need a code that does not intervene with those, because it should work on almost all computers not only on some.